# Tilde character spacing too large while using fractions

Tags: equations, align, amsmath, tcolorbox

I am facing a strange issue while using \tilde option in LaTex : I keep having a very large space between the tild character and the letter related to like this (in the second line) :

[image]

The fact is that, I have copy-pasted the concerned lines in a new document and this error doesn't show up anymore so I don't know if you would be able to get it :

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\begin{document}

\begin{align*}
\underline{n} \cdot \underline{\sigma} \cdot \underline{n} 
&= \frac{{\color{red}\rho g L}}{1 + \left(\frac{\partial \overline{h}}{\partial \overline{r}}\right)^2} \left(\left(2 \frac{\partial \overline{w}}{\partial \overline{z}} - \bar{p}   \right)  - 2\frac{\partial \overline{h}}{\partial \overline{r}} \left(\frac{\partial \overline{w}}{\partial \overline{r}} + \frac{\partial \overline{u}}{\partial \overline{z}} \right) - \left(\frac{\partial \overline{h}}{\partial \overline{r}} \right)^2 \left(\bar{p} - 2 \frac{\partial \overline{u}}{\partial \overline{r}}   \right) \right) = -P_T \\
&= \frac{{\color{red}\rho g L}}{1 + {\color{red} \epsilon^2} \Bigl(\frac{\partial \tilde{h}}{\partial \tilde{r}}\Bigr)^2} \left(\left(2 {\color{red}\epsilon^3} \frac{\partial \tilde{w}}{\partial \tilde{z}} - {\color{red}\epsilon} \tilde{p}   \right)  - 2 {\color{red}\epsilon} \frac{\partial \tilde{h}}{\partial \tilde{r}} \left({\color{red}\epsilon^4}\frac{\partial \tilde{w}}{\partial \tilde{r}} + {\color{red}\epsilon^2}\frac{\partial \tilde{u}}{\partial \tilde{z}} \right) - {\color{red}\epsilon^2} \left(\frac{\partial \tilde{h}}{\partial \tilde{r}} \right)^2 \left({\color{red}\epsilon}\tilde{p} - 2 {\color{red}\epsilon^3} \frac{\partial \tilde{u}}{\partial \tilde{r}}   \right) \right) = \frac{-D {\color{red}\epsilon}}{{\color{red}L^3}} (\Delta_{\tilde{r}}^{2} \tilde{h})
\end{align*}

\end{document}
```

Could anyone help me to understand what could be this issue related to ?

Thank you in advance,

Comment: Sorry, but if the code you show doesn't produce the issue, how could we diagnose?

Comment: @egreg I don't know to be honest... I have tried several things to learn where does it come from (since it's not even an error it makes it even more difficult to spot) and I don't know why it doesn't appear in particular documents... I was hoping for someone who has encountered the same issue...

Comment: Are you sure this is not a PDF viewer issue? Try a different PDF viewer. Otherwise as egreg says, when it is not reproducable there is not much we can do. BTW: does this code actually generate the image? The colors are different.

Comment: @daleif Is there any other way to write a tilde character ? (I have tried a different PDF viewer and it doesn't work...) Yes, I have changed the color for the purpose of the post because the original color is a "customized" one...

Comment: As long as it cannot be reproduced. We cannot do much. It would be good if you could provide a log of a compilation that generated these wrong tildes. Then we can get some idea about your system.

Comment: @Wiss The best you can to do understand and debug the issue yourself is probably to read Appendix G of the TeXbook (be prepared for some challenge :). Also relevant: [tb86jackowski.pdf](https://tug.org/TUGboat/tb27-1/tb86jackowski.pdf) and [vieth2008.pdf](http://www.gust.org.pl/projects/e-foundry/math-support/vieth2008.pdf).

Comment: Does your document by any chance load the `physics` package?

Comment: do not try to make a small example starting from empty, always start from a copy of your document and delete things checking at each stage the problem still shows. Post the smallest version that still shows the problem. If you delete something and the bad layout goes, you have found the cause.

Answer (score 1):

I have no problem with vertical spacing of the tildes. On another hand, the formula overflows into the default margin, so I added a third line and use the `geometry package.`
I took the opportunity to simplify the code for partial derivatives with the `diffcoeff` package and replaced most \overlines (for narrow letters) with a simple `\bar`.

Here is the code and its result:

```
    \documentclass{article}

    \usepackage{mathtools}
    \usepackage{diffcoeff}
    \usepackage{amssymb}
    \usepackage{xcolor}
    \usepackage[showframe]{geometry}

    \begin{document}

    \begin{align*}
    \underline{n} \cdot \underline{\sigma} \cdot \underline{n}
    &= \frac{{\color{red}\rho g L}}{1 + \left(\diffp{\bar{h}}{\bar{r}}\right)^2} \left(\left(2 \diffp{\overline{w}}{\bar{z}} - \bar{p} \right) - 2\diffp{\bar{h}}{\bar{r}} \left(\diffp{\overline{w}}{\overline{r}} + \frac{\partial \overline{u}}{\partial \overline{z}} \right) - \left(\frac{\partial \overline{h}}{\bar{r}} \right)^{\!\!2} \left(\bar{p} - 2 \diffp{\bar{u}}{\bar{r}} \right) \right) = -P_T \\
    &= \frac{{\color{red}\rho g L}}{1 + {\color{red} \epsilon^2} \Bigl(\diffp{\tilde{h}}{\tilde{r}}\Bigr)^2} \left(\left(2 {\color{red}\epsilon^3} \diffp{\tilde{w}}{\tilde{z}} - {\color{red}\epsilon} \tilde{p} \right) - 2 {\color{red}\epsilon} \diffp{\tilde{h}}{\tilde{r}} \left({\color{red}\epsilon^4}\diffp{\tilde{w}}{\tilde{r}} + {\color{red}\epsilon^2}\frac{\partial \tilde{u}}{\partial \tilde{z}} \right) - {\color{red}\epsilon^2} \left(\diffp{\tilde{h}}{\tilde{r}} \right)^{\!\!2} \left({\color{red}\epsilon}\tilde{p} - 2 {\color{red}\epsilon^3} \diffp{\tilde{u}}{\tilde{r}} \right) \right)\\
     &= \frac{-D {\color{red}\epsilon}}{{\color{red}L^3}}\Bigl (\Delta_{\tilde{r}}^{2} \tilde{h}\Bigr)
    \end{align*}

    \end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I am also unable to reproduce the behavior of the "tilde" accent character shown in the screen shot you posted.

I'd like so suggest that you replace all `\left` and `\right` sizing directives with `\biggl` and `\biggr`, respectively -- both to save on horizontal whitespace and to avoid sizing inconsistencies. And, I'd suggest adding line breaks in two locations to avoid overfull lines. Replacing all instances of `\overline` with `\bar` may also be a good idea.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath} % for "align*" environment
\usepackage{xcolor}  % for "\textcolor" macro
\providecommand\red[1]{\textcolor{red}{#1}} % handy shortcut macro

\begin{document}

\begin{align*}
\underline{n} \cdot \underline{\sigma} \cdot \underline{n}
&= \frac{\red{\rho g L}}{1 + 
  \bigl(\frac{\partial\bar{h}}{\partial\bar{r}}\bigr)^{\!2^{\mathstrut}}}
\biggl[
\biggl(2 \frac{\partial\bar{w}}{\partial\bar{z}} - \bar{p} \biggr)
- 2\frac{\partial\bar{h}}{\partial\bar{r}} \biggl(\frac{\partial\bar{w}}{\partial\bar{r}} + \frac{\partial\bar{u}}{\partial\bar{z}} \biggr)
- \biggl(\frac{\partial\bar{h}}{\partial\bar{r}} \biggr)^{\!\!2}
  \biggl(\bar{p} - 2 \frac{\partial\bar{u}}{\partial\bar{r}} \biggr)
\biggr] \\[1\jot]
&= -P_T \\
&= \frac{\red{\rho g L}}{1 + \red{\epsilon^2}
  \bigl(\frac{\partial\tilde{h}}{\partial\tilde{r}}\bigr)^{\!2^{\mathstrut}}}
\biggl[
\biggl(2 \red{\epsilon^3} \frac{\partial\tilde{w}}{\partial\tilde{z}} - \red{\epsilon} \tilde{p} \biggr)
- 2 \red{\epsilon} \frac{\partial\tilde{h}}{\partial\tilde{r}} \biggl(\red{\epsilon^4}\frac{\partial\tilde{w}}{\partial\tilde{r}} 
+ \red{\epsilon^2}\frac{\partial\tilde{u}}{\partial\tilde{z}} \biggr) \\
&\qquad - \red{\epsilon^2}
\biggl(\frac{\partial\tilde{h}}{\partial\tilde{r}} \biggr)^{\!\!2}
\biggl(\red{\epsilon}\tilde{p} - 2 \red{\epsilon^3} \frac{\partial\tilde{u}}{\partial\tilde{r}} \biggr)
\biggr] \\[1\jot]
 &= \frac{-D \red{\epsilon}}{\red{L^3}} (\Delta_{\tilde{r}}^{\!2} \tilde{h})
\end{align*}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 0):

I found the cause of this problem : it's in the use of the "accents" package :

```
\usepackage{accents}
```

I don't know the real reason behind this issue but it seems like this package interferes a bit with the other packages that I use (`\usepackage{physics}`) :  by deleting it I get normal tilde characters in my equations.

Thank you for everyone who tried to help despite the fact that my problem was "invisible" for all !

Comment: That information would have been useful earlier (both `accents` and `physics` the latter is generally not recommended due to bad programming).

Comment: @daleif The fact is that use a ton of different packages and I was not suspecting one of them in particular so it was difficult to precise everything in a concise way for the purpose of the post but thank you for your help.

Comment: This process of reducing is a very important tool in debugging issues like this.